# Java JLibav/Bridj UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, macos, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have something of a general question about all the possible causes for getting *UnsatisfiedLinkError* when doing Java/JNI type stuff.

Specifically, I am working with a Java project (JLibav) that I'm trying to build for Mac (Linux works).  So, I'm obviously getting that error; however, the library does get found and I am able to call other functions that are in the library!?  And, yes, I verified (via *fprintf* statement) that the function was being entered.

Also, using ***nm***, I have verified that the symbol in question is indeed there.  So, what else could possibly be goind on?  I did build the C/C++ Libav being used by JLibav, and when I configured the library (Libav), I did select "enable PIC" (position-independent code).  So, what else could cause that specific error?  Also, saw another function that was causing the same error, but when I debug and step into the code, the error is not hit!  Timing issue?

This is starting to seem like a threading issue or something, but how could that cause *UnsatisfiedLinkError*?  That doesn't make sense.

Thanks in advance ...  Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It might be related to issues with the `rpath`. Are you compiling with these kinds of flags for FFmpeg or Libav https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/0.11/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-2.6.1-macosx.patch ?

Comment: I did not know about those flags and I greatly appreciate that you've brought them to my attention!!  Thank you so very much!!